# Adding a if condition in a custom loss mse function

Tags: python, keras, mse

I'm trying to use a custom loss mse function with keras to put more emphasize on small value of a DNN model.

I did try something like this:

```
import keras.backend as K
def scaled_mse(y_true,y_pred):
    loss = K.square(y_pred - y_true)
    if y_true>0.1:
        loss=loss/K.abs(y_true)
     return loss
```

The input of my ML model is 41 value. The output just 1 value.

But it returns this error:
OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed in Graph execution. Use Eager execution or decorate this function with @tf.function.

Thanks for any help !

Comment: Can you scale the input values? For example, if 41 is the largest (absolute) value then divide everything by 41. Also, before you start down this road have you tried plotting your residuals? It might reveal deeper problems with the model itself

Comment: Well the 41 values are synthetic data that represents some "true" events somehow. I'd rather not touch them as it is much more simple to work directly with the mse value.
Thus I haven't thought of how to scale it if possible, but that might be tricky.

Answer (score 3):

The issue with your code is that the `if` operator is not differentiable per keras backend.  However, if you think about the differentiation for this operation, it is rather straightforward; the gradient is dependent on one term only if the conditional evaluates True, and likewise the other term if the conditional evaluates False. Thus, the fix should be simple. Keras backend provides the `switch()` operation I believe which is essentially a differentiable form of a conditional statement. Try using that instead.

`switch()` takes three arguments: the first is a conditional expression, the second a tensor from which values are taken if the conditional evaluates to true, and the third a tensor from which values are taken if the conditional evaluates to false. So your code might look something like this:

```
import keras.backend as K
def scaled_mse(y_true,y_pred):

   # both loss and scale loss are size 41

   loss = K.square(y_pred - y_true)
   scaled_loss = loss/K.abs(y_true)

   # first arg (bool expression) will evaluate to a bool tensor of size 41, 
   # which then indicates from which tensor to select the value for each 
   # element of the output tensor

   scale_mse_loss = K.switch((y_true > 0.1),scaled_loss,loss)
   return scale_mse_loss
```

Comment: Ok, so basically, any operation that has to be done within the mse function should be done using tf function.
I'll check on your solution ! Thanks for the help !

Comment: Any time you are using a loss function to accumulate gradients for training a neural network, all operations in the loss function (or any prior or subsequent functions) must have differentiable expressions implemented by the keras backend. Otherwise, the automatic gradient computation fails and you get the above graph error because keras doesn't know how to do gradient calculations for just any old python function.

Comment: Just a quick update,
I'm trying to use the tensorflow library as it seems more flexible than keras backend.
Thus the if statement in tensorflow is written like this in tf example:

```
z = tf.multiply(a, b)
result = tf.cond(x < y, lambda: tf.add(x, z), lambda: tf.square(y))
```

What the importance\use of the lambda:   in the statement ?